# Split yearly sales into monthly sales using a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, forecast

I am very new to SQL, but hope you can assist me in this logic. I need help to write this function in SQL Server (SQL Server Management Studio). I have a launch date, and sales summarized in years.

Currently my data looks like this:

**Sales Table**

| Project Name | Launch date | Sales Y1 | Sales Y2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 2021-01-01 | 15000 | 25000 |
| Project 2 | 2021-06-01 | 15000 | 25000 |
| Project 3 | 2021-03-01 | 10000 | 60000 |
| Project 4 | 2021-12-01 | 75000 | 70000 |

And I would like to change it to

**Forecast**

| Project Name | Sales month | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-02-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-03-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-04-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-05-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-06-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-07-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-08-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-09-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-10-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-11-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2021-12-01 | 1250 |
| Project 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2083 |
| Project 1 | 2021-03-01 | 2083 |
| Project 1 | 2021-04-01 | 2083 |
| Project 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2083 |
| Project 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2083 |
| Project 1 | 2021-02-01 | 2083 |
| Project 1 | 2021-03-01 | 2083 |
| ****Etc**...** |  |  |

So what it is doing is that it splits the yearly sales (Sales Y1) into 12 rows, that are placed after the launch date, than it takes the other 12 rows (Sales Y2) and places the other 12 rows after the first 12.

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Is it your data summarized and you are dividing by 12 by this reason?

Comment: In SQL you'd write a recursive query for this. Do you know how to do that? It is rather simple for a task like this. An alternative may be a stored procedure (but I don't know what you can and cannot do in SQL Servers stored procedures, so I may be wrong.)

Comment: James, yeah, the data is pulled from another table that is summarized into years.

Comment: I dont have any experience with recursive queries, sorry no - Thorsten

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this:

```
with ydata as (
  select 'Project 1' as ProjectName, convert(date,'2021-01-01') as LaunchDate, 15000 as SalesY1,25000 as SalesY2 union all
  select 'Project 2','2021-06-01',15000,25000 union all
  select 'Project 3','2021-03-01',10000,60000 union all
  select 'Project 4','2021-12-01',75000,70000
),
mnt as (
  select 1 as n, convert(date,'20210101',112) as d
  union all
  select n + 1, dateadd(month,1,d)
  from mnt
  where n < 24
)
select 
  ProjectName, d as SalesMonth, 
  case 
    when year(d) = 2021 then SalesY1/12
    else SalesY2/12 
  end as Sales
from mnt m
  cross join ydata d
order by ProjectName, d
```

You can test on [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff8a5514ee87d41bfd67b27e70dca662)

Comment: Amazing! 

I will try to fiddle with it a bit! The sales volumes, project names and dates come from another table called "SKU".. 

I will try to change the code accordingly